# Server aborted the SSL handshake error

Tags: node.js, ssl, hapi.js

I can't get a server running behind HTTPS working node.js. My goal is to get a Hapi server running with a self-signed certificate.

This was how I generated my self-signed certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
rm csr.pem
```

This is how I start the server in Hapi:

```
server.connection({
    port: 9920,
    tls: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './cert/key.pem')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './cert/cert.pem')),
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    routes: {
        cors: true
    }
 });
```

In order to verify it wasn't a Hapi only issue, I verified that this also doesn't work in vanilla node.js:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './cert/key.pem')), 
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './cert/cert.pem')),
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var a = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Both of these servers throw the same error in curl:

```
$ curl -kiv https://localhost:9920
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:9920/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 9920 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9920 (#0)
* Server aborted the SSL handshake
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

Versions:

- node: v4.1.1
- npm: 3.4.0

What's going on?

Comment: If the server aborted the handshake you need to look at the server side for errors, not at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on ssl as not used it much but if you check this code the options set is different to what you have configured.

https://github.com/hapijs/university/blob/master/lib/config.js#L6

The key and cert may have not been created correctly, check these docs to ensure you are using methods properly [hapi](http://hapijs.com/api#serverconnectionoptions) & [node](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)